# AttributeError: 'HTMLParserTreeBuilder' object has no attribute 'initialize_soup'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, attributeerror

I want to use BeautifulSoup for web scraping. I installed BeautifulSoup4 with pip and I have Python version 3.6. This is my code:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
```

And the error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-65-43556f5c0560>", line 1, in <module>
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

File "C:\Users\WH437EQ\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 241, in __init__
self.builder.initialize_soup(self)

AttributeError: 'HTMLParserTreeBuilder' object has no attribute 'initialize_soup'
```

Also I tried with:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html5lib")
```

and I got error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-72-e6a35e1f6f46>", line 1, in <module>
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html5lib")

File "C:\Users\WH437EQ\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 241, in __init__
self.builder.initialize_soup(self)

AttributeError: 'HTML5TreeBuilder' object has no attribute 'initialize_soup'
```

as well as with lxml:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "lxml")
```

And I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-73-0c396f083390>", line 1, in <module>
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "lxml")

File "C:\Users\WH437EQ\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 197, in __init__
    builder = builder_class()

File "C:\Users\WH437EQ\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\_lxml.py", line 105, in __init__
    self.nsmaps = [self.DEFAULT_NSMAPS_INVERTED]

AttributeError: 'LXMLTreeBuilder' object has no attribute 'DEFAULT_NSMAPS_INVERTED'
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: worked fine for me. Only thing I can think of is try to do `pip3` install instead of just `pip` because you're using python 3.x (Possible at some point you're initial python was not 3.x)

Comment: or actually, you have anaconda distribution, so try `conda install -c conda-forge beautifulsoup4`

Comment: Great! Thank you, this worked!